# 500 http status routing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs application, and I'm using `ui-router` for routing.

I have a state as following :

```
.state('core.page500', {
        url: '/page500',
        templateUrl: 'views/tmpl/pages/page500.html'
      })
```

And I want that whenever some api call returns 500 as an HTTP status in my application to route me to this state.

Is this possible in AngularJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at a concept called [Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

You are basically creating a service which gets triggered with every $http call. It looks like follows:

```
 angular
  .module( 'interceptors', [])
  .factory('HttpInterceptors', HttpInterceptors);

HttpInterceptors.$inject = ['$q', '$injector'];

function HttpInterceptors($q, $injector) {
  return {
    // On request success
    request: function (config) {
      // console.log(config); // Contains the data about the request before it is sent.

      // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
      return config || $q.when(config);
    },

    // On request failure
    requestError: function (rejection) {
      //console.log('rejection', rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.

      // Return the promise rejection.
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },

    // On response success
    response: function (response) {
      // console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.

      // Return the response or promise.
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },

    // On response failture
    responseError: function (rejection) {
      if(rejection.status === 500) {
        var state = $injector.get('$state');
        state.go('core.page500');
      }

      // Return the promise rejection.
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
}
```

Then, you push this inside the `$routeProvider` in the .config part of your app:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptors');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
What you'll need to do is 
Create a custom interceptor factory which checks the response.status and runs the reroute code if status === 500, and attach it to angularJS http interceptors.

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Try googling for angularJS custom http interceptors for detailed implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Http Interceptor. I haven't tested this, so let me know if it doesn't work, but this is pretty close to what you'll need:

```
angular.module('YourModule').factory('errorHttpInterceptor', ['$injector', '$q', '$state', errorHttpInterceptor]);

    function errorHttpInterceptor($injector, $q, $state) {
        return {
            responseError: function (error) {
                if (error.status === 500) {
                   $state.go('core.page500');
                }
                return $q.reject(error);
            }
        };
    }
```

And then to add it into the http pipeline:

```
angular.module('YourModule').config(['$httpProvider', config]);

function config($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorHttpInterceptor');
}
```

This will catch all 500 errors and send the user to your error page.